# Which XCode version having iOS 4.3.5 installed?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5, ios4

Currently I have Mac OS X Lion and Xcode 4.2 with the iOS 5 SDK. I also have an iPhone 4 with iOS 5 installed, but I want to run my app with the iOS 4.3.5 SDK.

Which Xcode version has iOS 4.3.5 SDK installed and which Mac OS version supports that version?

Is it possible to downgrade iOS 5 to iOS 4.3.5 on a device?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your app on 4.3, launch XCode 4.2, go to preferences, then from the  "Downloads" section choose to install the 4.3 Simulator.

Comment: Please let me know, Which Xcode version has iOS 4.3.5 SDK installed and which Mac OS version supports that version?

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember any xcode version with iOS SDK 4.3.5. Xcode 3.2.6 used to come with 4.3 SDK. In case you want to use 4.3 SDK, you can copy 4.3 SDK into the sdks directory in Xcode 4.2 itself and restart the xcode to use the 4.3 sdk.